# How do I get the n-value used in tests and graphs using R?

Tags: r, statistics

This might be trivial, but how do I get an output about how many datapoints were used in a test or a graph?

For example, I made a friedman test using `friedman.test(data$Behaviour_1_Mean, data$Condition, data$ID)` to see how the behaviour differed per ID between the conditions and then built a corresponding graph with `ggplot(data, aes(y = Behaviour_1_Mean, group = Condition, x= Condition))`

In a second example, I used wilcoxon test to check for differences between two groups (lights on or off) for a behaviour with `wilcox.test(data$Behaviour_2_Mean ~ data§LightsOn_or_Off, paired= FALSE, exact=FALSE)` and made a corresponding boxplot with `ggplot(data2, aes(y=Behaviour_2_Mean, group= factor(LightsOn_or_Off), x= factor(LightsOn_or_Off)))`

However, in both examples I don't know the respective number of observations that is used in my calculation and graph. How can I give out these n-values?

I'm still very new to R, need this for my master thesis and appreciate any help!

Comment: You should provide some fake data for us to work with, but in general you would calculate that outside of the test, e.g. `table(data$ID)` to count the number with each `ID`, or `table(data$LightsOn_or_Off)`.

Comment: If unsure, what a function has in offer - beyond the default printed or plotted summary - you can store the result (e. g. `friedman_result <- friedman.test(...)`, usually a list) and inspect its structure like `str(friedman_result)` (or scrutinize `?friedman.test`). Extract the item of interest, e. g. p-value, as you would do with other lists (`[[`, `$`). Moreover you can examine the components of a ggplot via `ggplot_build(your_plot_here)`.